# Memory engine table giving inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1-log - Ubuntu 22.04

I have a relatively complex application that is making use of temporary memory (engine) tables. The tables are generated from select insert statements and then the data is manipulated. After which a series of selects are performed with one or more rejoins to the same table.

The tables have 8 indexes created with the table create statement some are hash and some are btree.

Doing exactly the same process using exactly the same data I am getting slightly different results (in terms of data return and the number of rows).

It's taken me a while to get to the root of this, I have figured out that the temp memory tables are identical in terms of data and the database calls are the same.

I have let the tables be created as permanent memory tables so I can see them in myphpadmin, rename them, and let them be created again. Then run the same query against each table, and I get different results. The table checksums are identical, row count is identical. but the same query gives different results when tables as memory engine. Convert them both to INNODB and both give the same result... is the memory engine broken?

Has anyone ever seen this before and got any ideas about what might be going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without reproducible data, queries etc. Take advantage of the 10.6.11 upgrade, there's [some quite important fixes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10-6-11-release-notes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, in case anyone is interested or has this same issue.

In my query, I have an order by and limit 1

example.

```
SELECT * FROM `tmp_lookup` T2
   WHERE
      T2.`from_location` = 'location1'
      T2.`to_location` = 'location2'
      T2.`depart_time` > '1970-01-01 22:14:00'
      ORDER BY T2.`depart_time` ASC
      LIMIT 1;
```

In the above example, when ordering by depart_time and limiting to 1, if there is more than one row with the same smallest depart_time it will return a random 1st row from the ones with the same value, depending on the table.

If you build a memory table and do the query it will consistently pick the same first row, delete the table, remake the table, rerun the query and it will consistently pick another first row.

I have no firm idea why, but I guess as it's in memory and not on disk the order of the rows in the table is 'random' utter guess.